solana-program-test fails with termcolor lifetime issues
I'm trying to start a program using solana-program-test, but I'm having trouble getting the examples in SPL to run.
If I use the examples/rust/transfer-lamports program, extract it into its own project, and try using "cargo test-sbf" I get many errors about lifetimes in the termcolor crate. Here is the first:
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
   --> /home/fzzyyti/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/termcolor-1.4.1/src/lib.rs:464:30
    |
464 |     StdoutLock(io::StdoutLock<a>),
    |                              ^ expected named lifetime parameter
    |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
    |
463 ~ enum IoStandardStreamLock<'a, a> {
464 ~     StdoutLock(io::StdoutLock<'a, a>),
    |


It builds with no errors for "cargo build-sbf".
I'm guessing it is trying to build the solana-sdk in sbf architecture. solana-sdk is in the dev dependencies, so I don't think it is supposed to.
Am I missing something that will allow this to run with "cargo test-sbf"?
I'm using
solana --version 1.18.15
SPL repo latest master branch

It seems like this is a real issue with termcolor for the non-sbf part of the program.
I resolved this by downgrading termcolor with
termcolor = "=1.4.0" under [dev-dependencies] in Cargo.toml, which are compiled to my local architecture.
I ran into the same issue in a different rust program not compiling to SBF and fixed it by downgrading termcolor in the [dependencies] section.
